# Google App Script Issue with Document ID Handling

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to insert the first 300 characters of a document into a spreadsheet cell.
This works unless I try to iterrate.

When it is added to a while loop, instead of returning the document ID it is returning the document title. I have tried file.getUrl and file.getId as well. Those will work in an array, and insert in the spreadsheet until I try and use them to extract the document content. This should be as easy as the other items I am adding to the spreadsheet. Any ideas appreciated.

**This returns the first 300 characters of the document in the specified URL.**

```
    function readDocumentText() {
      var url = file.getUrl();
      var theUrlid = url.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);
    
      var theUrlid = url.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);
      var focusId = theUrlid;
      var doccon = DocumentApp.openById(focusId);
      var body = doccon.getBody();
      var text = body.getText().substring(0, 300);
      Logger.log("Document Text: " + text);
      return text;
    
    }
```

However, if it is inside of this function, it returns the document title.

```
function folderLoop(){
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var list = [];
var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Curriculum").next();
var folders = parentFolder.getFolders();

 while (folders.hasNext()) {

  var folder = folders.next();

    var files = folder.getFiles();

      while (files.hasNext()){
        var file = files.next();
         var url = file.getUrl();
         var theUrlid = url.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);

         function readDocumentText() {
          var theUrlid = url.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);
          var focusId = theUrlid;
         var doccon = DocumentApp.openById(focusId);
          var body = doccon.getBody();
         var text = body.getText().substring(0, 300);
       // Logger.log("Document Text: " + text);
        return text;

}}
```

Comment: file is undefined in readDocumentText()

Comment: are you sure that folders only contain google docs?

Comment: I will check the folder contents.

Comment: I found a couple of PDFs. They broke the loop. I need to add some error handling. Thanks!

Comment: You could use getFilesByType()